# Gradle syncing keeps failing

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to include [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) into my Android project using Gradle. Here's my `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
    }
}
```

When I try to sync it, I keep getting the following error.

**No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)**

I'm very new to Android so I'm clueless on how to correct this. Can anyone please help me out? I'm using Android Studio version 0.5.8 by the way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include dependencies in your top-level build file. Include them in module-level build files instead. If you use the Project Structure UI instead of modifying build files directly, it will set things up properly.